# How can I execute this function for range of values?

Tags: function, matlab

I have this function
[image]
where f has values (18 19 20 21 22), and I should compute the value of the function for each value of f and plot each value.
I try to make f as vector 18:22, but it gives result from 1 to 22. Same result when I use for loop. My code is below, how can I modify it to take the values within the range only?

```
clc
fc=20;
theta=80;
N=16;
f=18:22;
g_m(f)=(sin((N*pi/2).*sin(theta).*(f/fc-1)))./sqrt(N).*(sin(pi/2).*(f/fc-1));
g_p(f)=exp(1j*0.5*(N-1).*pi*sin(theta).*(f/fc-1));
gain(f)=g_m(f).*g_p(f);
figure(1);
plot(f,g_m(f));
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It seems that your question qould be answered by yourself if you would have debugged your code, please read [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should give you enough information:

```
f = 5:7;
g(f)= [2, 2, 5]
g =  
   0   0   0   0   2   2   5
```